# Are the manuscripts of the Ramchal's letters available online?

Tags: ramchal, manuscripts

I am currently reading *Igros Ramchal* published by Machon Ramchal (Rabbi Mordechai Shriki). One of the first letters in the book (ג1 on page יב) is from the Ramchal to his Rebbe, Rabbi Yeshayah Basan while the Ramchal was taking a bit of a vacation in a small city north of Padua. In this letter, the Ramchal explains a difficult Tosfos in mesechet Yuma. This letter has gotten me very excited since this is the only material I am aware of where the Ramchal quotes any source besides *Chazal* or *Tanach*. Not only that, but this is the only material I am aware of where the Ramchal "shows his work" so to speak, meaning that he shows **how** he arrived at a certain conclusion or, said a bit differently, **how** he learned something.

Because of the 2 reasons above, I am very interested in seeing the original manuscript to verify that the text I'm working with is accurate. Does anyone know where I can see the original manuscript?

I will attach 2 pictures from *Igros Ramchal* showing where the author got the text from.
[image]

[image]

Comment: According to the photos shown above, the manuscript copies are in the possession of an individual, Mr. Avraham Shisha of London. The manuscript listing is 'Katav Yad' Adler 292. You could check with the Bodelian Library to see if they have a copy of the manuscript or know how to contact Mr. Shisha. They are usually very helpful.

Comment: From what I am seeing on World Catalog, this may be referring to Rabbi Avraham Shisha Segal HaLevi.  They list the British Library, St. Pancras, London, NW1 2DB United Kingdom as possibly having some information.

Comment: There is also a special collection from Abraham Shisha HaLevi at the Leeds University Library in Leeds, West Yorkshire.